# Is it possible to set global rule in GitLab CI for branch run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I know how to make specific jobs to run only on certain branches, but I would like to set a global rule for the entire pipeline config, so I don't have to set it in each job separately.
Is that possible?

I'm currently putting this rule at the very top of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
# Define rules that the entire pipeline should only run for the given branch
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "some-custom-branch"'
    when: never
```

but my pipeline fails with this error:

[image]

And all the documentation I can find is only about defining branch rules in specific jobs, but not on global state level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set rules for the entire pipeline by using the global `workflow:rules:` key

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:  # only run pipelines on `main` branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

Comment: Alright, so I was missing the `workflow` parent prop... Thanks!